# Rxjs sequence of ajax calls depending on results from previous ones and handling errors

Tags: javascript, ajax, rxjs, reactive-programming

can you help me with turning the following promise-based scenario into rxjs streams?

```
async function createItem(...) {

    let newData, metadata;
    try {
        newData = await ajax('.../createItem', ...)
    } catch (e) {
        throw new Error('Can not create item', e);
    }

    try {
        metadata = await ajax('.../createMetadata', newData.id, ...);
    } catch (e) {
        throw new Error('Item created but metadata not', newData, e);
    }
    return {newData, metadata}
}
```

Is's just the flow when you have two-staged item creation process. 
For example, you first call ajax to create actual item, you get item id from the response
then you call another ajax to set some metadata of newly created item.

When success, you return the new metadata and new data. When saving actual item (first stage) fails, you get the error that neither actual object nor metadata was created.
If the actual object is created but metadata fails to save, you will get error that actual object was created however metadata not.

I am trying to implement that using Observable.concat, however I can't access the output from first ajax call in the second call.
I also tried with Observable.ajax(...).mergeMap(Observable.ajax(...))....
but then I don't know where the catch should be put to identify at which stage (1 or 2) the failure occured.

How you generally solve the problem, when you have sequence of events (where input of previous is needed for the next one) and want to produce full result combined from all ajax responses, or partial result combined with responses from first subsequent success ajax calls and the error message of the stage when it failed?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using RxJS 5.5 with pipable operators:

```
return ajax('.../createItem', ...)
  .pipe(
    catchError(e => {
      throw new Error('Can not create item', e);
    }),
    concatMap(newData => ajax('.../createMetadata', newData.id, ...)
      .pipe(
        map(metadata => ({ newData, metadata })),
        catchError(e => {
          throw new Error('Item created but metadata not', newData, e);
        }),
      )
    ),
  )
```

Comment: I guess you should create the first stream as `ajax('...')` looks like a promise. `import { fromPromise } from 'rxjs'; return fromPromise(ajax('...'))...`

Comment: If `ajax` returns a Promise then yes, you need to wrap it with `fromPromise`

Comment: is it critical to use pipes for my case? I don't fully understand what does pipe solve here.

Comment: It doesn't matter. If you're using RxJS 5.5 or newer it's recommended to use `pipe` but you can stay with the old style as well.

Comment: is the contactMap usage the key point here? I almost did the same before asking but using mergeMap

Comment: In this case you could use `switchMap`, `concatMap` or `mergeMap` at all of them would work because the source emits just one value and their behavior is different on how they treat the new Observable while the previous one is hasn't completed.